# How to make a function as default in azure function app?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an azure function app (abc.azurewebsites.net) and have a function named Function1 defined in it. (abc.azurewebsites.net/api/Function1?code=def==)

Is there a way in which, I can define this Function1 as default and all the incoming requests to abc.azurewebsites.net gets routed to my Function1?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-serverless-api#create-your-first-proxy) to get this.

Follow this tutorial, and the `Route template` should be `/`, and then you should change your function `authLevel` to `anonymous` like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook#trigger---java-examples).

1.Set the application setting add `HELLO_HOST`(any parameter same as the backend url) with value `<YourBackendApp>.azurewebsites.net`.

[image]

2.Create the proxy.

[image]

3.Set your function to `anonymous` then your function don't need API keys code to call it.

[image]

Then below my test result, it's a HTTP trigger function with query string `&name=<yourname>`.

[image]